# .NET Data Annotations for String formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC project and need some help for String formatting with data annotations.

So I have a String prop Id that has to be in this form: `nnn/nnnnn/nnn` (where n is for decimal value) AND the 3 last digits has to be: 999-the first 3 digits.

For example: `123/12345/876`

Can someone help me with this and understanding how the formatting actually works?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly at all? You say the last 3 digits have to be 999 but in your example they are 876

Comment: Also can you show an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @Glitch100 999 minus first 3 digits.   876+123=999

Comment: Are you expecting to do this with String.Format()? Or you just want to format the string like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: As I'm a beginner in C#, I wasn't aware that there was a `ValidationAttribute` class which allows me to make my own `DataAnnotation` to validate the ID. This is what I did:

- Make a class `IDVerification` that enhirits of `ValidationAttribute`
- Use this class in my Main class where I use ID by writing `[IDVerification]` above it.

If someone wants to see the class, it's [here](http://pastebin.com/7Zbw0VV3).

Answer (score 1):

In relation to your recent comment:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0;###/####")]
```

I believe, however I don't think you can do the logic required on the last part of the ID.

Hene the below solution. You could always just make the property `{get;` have that logic
...

```
int id = 123;
int middleId = 12345;

string propertyId = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",id,middleId,GetTrailingId(id).ToString());
```

...

```
private int GetTrailingId(int prefixId)
{
    const int upperLimit = 999;
    return upperLimit - prefixId;
}
```

Comment: Like I said it's a String (public String Id {get;set;}).

And I want to link a Data Annotation to it so that it formats the data entered on the View. Can't we use 'DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="XXX")]' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "123/12345/876";
var ints = input.Split('/').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
Debug.Assert(ints[0] + ints[2] == 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish but this snippet might be helpful.  If you provide more information, we might be able to help more.  This snippet formats the decimals as if they were integers and assumes there are two numbers being output.  Was the first slash supposed to represent the decimal point and so in actuality, there was only one number involved in that string?

```
class MyClass
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public decimal OtherNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:000}/{1:0000}/{2:000}", this.Id, this.OtherNumber,  999.0m - this.Id );
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new MyClass { Id = 123.0m, OtherNumber = 1234.0m }); // 123/1234/876
        Console.WriteLine(new MyClass { Id = 12.3m, OtherNumber = 123.4m }); // 012/1234/987
    }
}
```

For more information about formatting strings, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx